# Focal length needed to photograph card table

Tags: lens

I am attempting to photograph a square card table 35 inches on each side, including some breathing room.  I am using a Panasonic G6 with 14-24mm kit lens, at 14mm.  On line calculators indicate that with a 14mm lens and image size of 13.5mm (the MFT sensor height), that a focal length of 14mm would be wide enough at a distance of 1 meter from the table.  When I tried it, I had to get 12 feet away to get everything in.  What is the maximum focal length that will work for at a distance of 1 meter?

Comment: Why is it necessary to involve complicated math ?  just set up your shot,  look through the camera, make adjustment to camera position and/or lens.  It does not need to be rocket science, if 12 feet is good then use 12 feet.

Comment: I think the kit lens is 14– **42**, not 14–24. Are you sure the lens was zoomed out to 14mm, and not zoomed in to 42mm? Did you have any digital zoom in camera enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Geometry says you should need roughly an angle-of-view of 80° which is what you would get from a 12mm lens on a Four-Thirds sensor.

The key is to understand that the aspect-ratio of the sensor is 4:3 and to capture a table of 36"x36" you need to fit at least 48"x36". This has a diagonal of 60" and the angle-of-view of lenses is specified according to their diagonal coverage.

Computing with a right-triangle of that covers half of a 60" diagonal gives just over 38 degrees, so you need twice that to capture the table, so a 14mm lens is just shy of being able to. The next widest focal-length is 12mm which you can find prime lenses easily and even a few zooms.

Comment: ITai is spot on - a tip of the hat from Alan Marcus

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your "online calculations" work but it sounds like you are photographing from above.  The table has a width of somewhat less than 1m (but you wanted breathing room, so let's take 1m).  At a distance of 1m, you should be able to get an image size of 13.5mm with a 13.5mm distance between lens and sensor.  If you focus at a distance of ∞, that is.  However, the additional dioptre you need brings 13.5mm of focal length just down to 13.3mm.

So your 12ft number appears somewhat strange.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trigonometry shows that the angle of view needed to capture a 1m wide surface from 1m should be on the order of about 53°. That's approximately a 35mm lens in the full-frame world - with an MFT crop factor of ~2, that should be about a 17mm lens on your rig.

Comment: How much does that lens *breathe* when focused closely? Focal lengths and AoVs are generally measured with the lens focused at infinity.

Comment: @MichaelC You can't really consider focus breathing when talking in generalities like this - you'd have to know the specific lens (and, yes, the question does mention a specific lens, but I intentionally kept the answer more generic). Even then, such specs aren't usually published, so it would probably have to be determined by careful testing.

Comment: Exactly. You can't really answer this question specifically without knowing the particulars of the lens. Considering that the OP had to back up to about 3.5 meters with a 14mm lens, it's highly likely that a 17mm lens in the same system isn't going to work.